# Swagger UI seems to not handle optional keys with POST json body

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, joi, hapi-swagger

### Packages :

```
hapi-swagger: 9.0.1
joi: 13.0.2
```

### Context :

I use the `swagger-ui` with a `swagger.json` file generated by `hapi-swagger`.

I use for `hapi-swagger` the `jsonEditor` option set to `true`.
Which means that i don't enter myself the body in a single text area but i use directly the generated inputs of the UI.

### Issue :

Only the key `"name"` is required in the payload, the other ones are optional by default if i refer to the `Joi` doc.

Actually the `Swagger-UI` sends :

```
curl -X POST
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
-d '{
 "name":"fzef",

 "idsUser": [],

 "idsUsergroup":[]
}'
```

Instead i want that the `Swagger-UI` to send a request like :

```
curl -X POST 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
-d '{
 "name":"fzef",
 }'
```

### Swagger UI

[image]

### Joi Schema

```
Joi.object().keys({

 request: Joi.object().keys({

     name: Joi.string().required(),

     idsUser: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()),

     idsUsergroup: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()),
   }),
  }),
 });
```

### Swagger.json

```
...
"paths": {
  "/addCompany": {
    "post": {
      "operationId": "postAddcompany",

       "parameters": [{
          "type": "string",
          "default": "1",
          "pattern": "/^v[0-9]+$/",
          "name": "apiVersion",
          "in": "path",
          "required": true
        },
        {
          "in": "body",
          "name": "body",
          "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Model 208"
           }
         }
       ],

      "tags": ["api", "CompanyCommandsAPIPart"],

      "responses": {
        "default": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          },
         "description": "Successful"
        },
      }
    }
  }
}

"definitions": {
  ...
  "Model 208": {
    "type": "object",

    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },

      "idsUser": {
         "$ref": "#/definitions/Model 13",
        "type": "array",
        "x-alternatives": [{
          "$ref": "#/x-alt-definitions/idsFunctionality",
          "type": "array"
        }, {
          "type": "string"
        }]
      },

      "idsUsergroup": {
         "$ref": "#/definitions/Model 13",
         "type": "array",
        "x-alternatives": [{
          "$ref": "#/x-alt-definitions/idsFunctionality",
          "type": "array"
        }, {
          "type": "string"
        }]
      },
    },

    "required": ["name"]
  },
  ...
}
```

---

What can i do to get this request body ?

Do i need to precise a `joi` method in order that the `hapi-swagger` parser add a parameter like `'optional'` to the `swagger.json` ?

I found the same issue for the query of a GET method but found no solution:

[https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/684](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtbHK.png)

Comment: The request body sent by Swagger UI is the one that you enter. Did you try entering `{"name": "fzef"}`?

Comment: Apologize i forgot to tell that i use the jsonEditor option of hapi-swagger, i will edit the post

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of request body config in Swagger UI?

Comment: Just did it above Joi schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JSON Editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor) component provides the "Properties" and "Edit JSON" buttons to customize the JSON payload, as you can in the component demo here: http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/. However, Swagger UI 2.x (the version used by hapi-swagger at the time of writing) initializes the JSON Editor with `disable_properties: true` and `disable_edit_json: true` so that these buttons are hidden, and the UI does not expose any configuration options to change the JSON Editor options. There is an open issue in the hapi-editor repository on GitHub: https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/issues/332.

A possible workaround is to tweak the Swagger UI code. Assuming your Swagger UI's `index.html` uses unminified `swagger-ui.js`, find the following lines in `<hapi-swagger>/public/swaggerui/swagger-ui.js`:

```
disable_properties:true,
disable_edit_json:true,
```

and replace them with:

```
disable_properties:false,
disable_edit_json:false,
```

Now the JSON Editor will have the "Object Properties" button. Click this button to select the properties to be displayed in the form editor and included in the request body. Unselected properties will not be sent in the request body.

[image: Swagger UI - JSON Editor - excluding optional properties]